# Access to unaligned memory location?

Tags: arm

I'm doing an assignment where I create another array by reading a given array. Below is the relevant code:

```
    .data
array_source:
    .word 42, 67, 81, 90, 124, -5
array_sink:
    .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
array_length:
    .word 6
add_amount:
    .word 5
    
    .text
    .global _start
_start: 
        
        ldr r8,=array_source
        ldr r0,=array_length
        ldr r3, [r3]
        
        ldr r4, =array_sink
        ldr r5, =add_amount
        ldr r5, [r5]
        
        mov r6, #1
        
begin_loop:               
        cmp r6, r3
        beq end_of_loop
        ldr r8, [r8]
        
        add r8, r8, r5
        str r8, [r4]
        
        add r6, r6, #1
        
        add r0, r0, #4
        add r4, r4, #4
        
        b begin_loop
```

ARMSim# gives me the error "access to unaligned memory location, bad address = 0000002f" on the second loop through `add r8, r8, r5` and I don't know why. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `ldr r0,=array_length`, `ldr r3, [r3]`, because address in `r0` but dereferencing by `r3`, I guess

Comment: well, whole memory accesses in the loop just a crap

Comment: I've changed it to ```ldr r3,=array_length``` and I'm getting the same error still.

Comment: cool, now fix access to elements of `array_source`

Comment: still nothing? alright `0000002f == 42 + 5`, no more hints from me.

Comment: Changed ldr r8, [r8] to [r0] and it fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: the array length is 6 WORDS...6 32 bit words, not 6 bytes.  and the increment amount also needs to be in words not bytes.